# Tensorflow textsum error of Versioning

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, textsum

I am trying to convert the training text file to bin file for training the textsum of tensorflow. But I encountered the following error:

```
$ python textsum/data_convert_example.py --command text_to_binary --in_file data/tt.txt --out_file data/bin_data_train
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "textsum/data_convert_example.py", line 12, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 104, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import test
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/test.py", line 57, in <module>
    import mock                # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top,unused-import
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mock/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mock.mock as _mock
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mock/mock.py", line 71, in <module>
    _v = VersionInfo('mock').semantic_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pbr/version.py", line 461, in semantic_version
    self._semantic = self._get_version_from_pkg_resources()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pbr/version.py", line 448, in _get_version_from_pkg_resources
    result_string = packaging.get_version(self.package)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pbr/packaging.py", line 755, in get_version
    name=package_name))
Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. It's also possible that there is a mismatch between the package name in setup.cfg and the argument given to pbr.version.VersionInfo. Project name mock was given, but was not able to be found.
```

Kindly help me. I am using tensorflow 1.2.0 with python 2.7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a problem with your install.

Please try the following commands:

`pip install --upgrade mock
pip install --upgrade distribute`

If it does not work, you should give us more details about how you installed tensorflow (pip? conda? clone & setup.py?) and try to reinstall from scratch.

Hope it helps

Comment: I only got this tensorflow error when distributing using pyinstaller, does the error come from an old mock or distribute version? Upgrade mock and distribute doesn't help, but clearly its grabbing some wrong combination.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (however not related to tensorflow) and in my case updating setuptools was the fix.
I've found the suggestion here:
https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock/issues/314

Before update I had setuptools 0.6c11 and I've updated to latest 39.2.0.

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

or actually in my case I had to download and install locally since production server has no connection to internet:

```
pip download setuptools

pip install setuptools-39.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```